# c++ why isn't there something like length(array)?

Tags: c++, arrays, language-design

Well I don't think that it's really important but since the program has to store the length because of delete[] anyway, Why can't we get this "stored information" ?

Comment: Because that's what the C++ standard says.

Comment: Not a real question, do you have code that you have a question about?

Comment: @trumpetlicks why not? I see it as a question about a language feature. It can be useful to know the motivation.

Comment: Tagged as `language-design`, it's a well-fit and on-topic question for this tag I think

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - I agree with Oli. Understanding motivation may be interesting, but it isnt going to change the standard. The standard is what it is, so Im not sure how USEFUL the motivation is, but interesting maybe.

Comment: @trumpetlicks motivation (for making a choice in design) is very useful, not just interesting.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - Quoted from SO FAQ - "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." How is this NOT an open ended, non-specific problem solving question? There is NO specific problem this question is trying to solve!  You are right, I think it an INTERESTING question, but not necessarily an SO question.

Comment: @trumpetlicks people from the C++ standards committe are also on SO. It's not open-ended if one of them comes and says "we didn't implement that because X and Y". And then we all learn something that might help us in the future, when we're designing our own language.

Comment: I think it comes down to this: array new is kind of a kludge; most effort has been put into replacing it with something better, not trying to patch around its many inadequacies, especially since *most* of them are unfixable anyway.

Comment: As I read it, the question is not "Why didn't they design the language differently?", but rather "How does this limitation make sense, even though it looks like it doesn't make sense?" I think the first one is open-ended and chatty, while the second one is answerable.

Comment: It would be intresting to see an implementation of that, given that a T* could point to an array, or not... how will the implementation figure out that its not an array (given that you are allowed to interpret pointers as pointers to an array of length 1 almost everywhere)

Comment: Guys, it's a valid question; stop closing questions just because you can. There are *tons* of "why doesn't X have feature Y?" questions on SO, many well-upvoted. Just because someone is wondering about something, that doesn't make the question a poor fit for SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The implementation only needs to store the length, and typically only does, if the type is not trivially destructible (i.e., it needs to generate calls to a destructor) and the array was created with the new[] operator.

Since that property of the arrayed type bears no relation to the size of the array, it is more elegant simply to call the length "cookie" a private implementation detail.

To get the length of a complete array object (not a mere pointer), you can use `std::extent< decltype( arr ) >::value` or `std::end( arr ) - std::begin( arr )`.

Using `new[]` with a class with a destructor is a code smell. Consider `std::vector` instead. The overhead vs raw `new[]` (considering all bytes that need to be allocated, wherever they are) is one pointer's worth of bytes, and the benefits are innumerable.

Comment: Add to that it is not hard to get the length with what the language provides, e.g. with the standard template implementation.

Comment: Actually the overhead of `vector` is two pointers (or sizes), since it has to track both size and capacity. +1 anyway.

Comment: @MikeSeymour But subtract one pointer of overhead because the `length` cookie of the dynamic array is as big as a pointer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Mike is right, a vector is at _least_ the size of three pointers, which is an overhead of two pointers-worth.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure implementations _are_ allowed to allocate padding to store the length, it just shouldn't be returned to the caller is all.  I'm told some implementations keep the length at `int pointer[-1]`

Comment: @MooingDuck "The overhead **vs raw new[]** is one pointer's worth of bytes" — I am comparing it to `new[]` which has an overhead of one pointer (in the context "Using new[] with a class with a destructor").  Two minus one is one.

Comment: @MooingDuck The only case where padding is disallowed is for an array of `char`, give or take a `signed` or `unsigned`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I don't think you read my message.  A `vector` is at _least_ the size of three pointers.  Raw `new[]` stores only one pointer.  Three minus one is two pointers of overhead.  As for padding, if the allocator allocates it _before_ the pointer that's returned, you would never know it existed, and as far as I can see, that would obey the spec to the letter.  And as I said, MSVC _does do that_.

Comment: @MooingDuck And I don't think you're reading closely. A vector is three pointers. An array of nontrivially-destructible class is one pointer plus a "cookie" as big as a pointer. Three minus two is one, if you prefer it that way. I would't consider the pointer-to-array to be "overhead" in any sense. See my comment on Nathan's answer re the relationship of the allocator (more precisely, operator new[]) to the cookie. Anyway, I don't believe you'd downvote without comment for such a nitpick…

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Alright, I had misunderstood your comments then, and hadn't realized you were including the "cookie".  Your answer is great, except, I'm still unsure about the "implementation is not allowed to allocate any padding" sentance, but I have not yet downvoted.

Comment: @MooingDuck Well I just went and looked it up, and it is a special case, but padding isn't forbidden. Actually it says that if padding is applied, more may be required. That certainly discourages an implementation from doing things that way, but it's possible. Anyway, it's not a central point. Removed it and clarified the other part.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case:

```
char* a = new char[100];
```

Now `a` needs to point to a buffer that's at least 100 chars big, *but the system might have allocated a bigger buffer to fulfill this*.

With this in mind, we can see that the system is free to immediately forget the size the program asked for, as long as it can still deallocate the buffer properly later. (Either by remembering the size of the allocated buffer or doing the memory allocation with some smart data structure where only the pointer to the start is required)

So, in the general case, the information you are looking for is *not*, in fact, stored anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not all arrays are allocated by `new`.

```
void f(int* arr, size_t n)
{
  length(arr);  //  ???
}


int main()
{
  int a[5];
  f(a);
}
```

It's trivial to write though, just call `(std::end(arr) - std::begin(arr))`, although it only works for arrays, not pointers that point to the start of arrays.

Comment: The old `(sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr))` trick works too for real arrays, but I like the new style

Comment: Iterator subtraction can't be (easily) optimized to a constant. sizeof is, but it's less safe. `template <typename T, std::size_t N> constexpr std::size_t length(T(&)[N]) { return N; }` is safe and can optimize to a constant.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig, those aren't general iterators, they're pointers, and the difference between two addresses in the same array can be optimised to a constant.  And I suggested `end-begin` because that's trivial, whereas defining that function template is not trivial, it involves non-type template parameters and an ugly array declarator - not suitable for beginners!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the philosophy of c++ is to not force on people any feature that has a potential cost unless unavoidable.

There may be additional costs in storing this information, and the user may not want to pay that cost if they don't need the information. And as it's trivial to store the length yourself if you want it there is no reason to provide a language feature that has a cost to everyone using an array.

Answer (score 1):

For **proper** arrays, that is, `int a[length]`, you already have that facility: just do

```
#define length(A) (sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A))
```

and you are done with it.

If you are talking about getting the length of the array pointed to by a pointer, well, pointers and arrays are two different concepts and coupling them makes no sense, even if proper arrays "decays" to pointers when needed and you access arrays through pointer arithmetic.

But even if we don't take that into account and talk about technological aspects, the `C++` runtime may not know what the length of your array is, since `new` could rely on `malloc`, which stores the length of the array in its specific ways, which is understood only by `free`: the `C++` runtime only stores extra informations only when you have non-empty destructors. A pretty messy picture, huh?

Comment: You can also use std::extent<decltype(A)>::value.

Answer (score 0):

because its up to the implementation where it stores this information. so there is no general way to do a length(array)

Comment: `length(array)` could be up to the implementation as well.

Answer (score 0):

The length is most certainly not stored on all implementations.  C++, for example, allows for garbage collection (e.g. boehmgc), and many collectors do not need to know the length.  In traditional allocators, the length stored will often be larger than the actual length, i.e. the length allocated, not the length used.

Comment: The length (number of objects, not bytes) does need to be stored somewhere if the objects of the array have nontrivial destructors. Such a mechanism is transparent to the allocator, which blindly allocates some padding bytes for the implementation. GC with non-POD objects is a new and bleeding-edge feature.

Comment: yes, but that's only a subset of cases, and I can think of ways of avoiding storing the length (e.g. sentinel keys.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean to use padding bytes for the sentinel? What if there's no padding? Anyway, all implementations do it the same way, so "not stored on all implementations" is wrong… although it's also true that there are cases where no implementation stores a length value. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

But, what exactly is the length of the array? Is it the number of bytes in the array or the number of elements in the array?

For example : for some class A of 100 byte size,

A* myArray = new A[100];

should length(myArray) return 100 or 100 * 100? Somebody might want 100, somebody might want 10000. So, there is no real argument for either of that.

Comment: C++ consistently favors counting objects, not bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The c++ type that works most like the "arrays" in languages that support `length(array)` is `std::vector<>`, and it *does* have `std::vector<>::size()`.

The size of plain `[]` arrays is known to the compiler in scopes where the size is explicit, of course, but it is possible to pass them to scopes where the size is *not* known to the compiler. This gives c++ *more* ways to handle array-like data than languages that must support a `length` interogative (because they have to insure that the size is always passed).